# Javascript make method run when post completes

Tags: javascript, http, post, postback

I have a simple python http server. Something like this - https://gist.github.com/bradmontgomery/2219997
I have a button within a form that calls the do_POST on the server once it completes. The result of the do_POST is returned to an iframe. Here is what the form on the client-side looks like:

```
    <form action = "/" method = "post" target="my_iframe">
       <section>
           txt1    : <input type = "text" name = "btn1"/>
           txt2     : <input type = "text" name = "btn2"/> 
           txt3: <input type = "text" name = "btn3"/> <br/>
       </section>
       <br>
         <input type = "submit" value = "Button" onclick="clearIFrame()"/>
    </form>
    <iframe id="my_iframe" name="my_iframe" width="700" height="20">
        </iframe>
```

Here are the contents of the clearIFrame method:

```
function clearIFrame(){    
  document.getElementById('my_iframe').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML = "";
}
```

The method that I call within do_POST on the server side (python code) takes about 3 seconds to execute. Then, it dumps the results to the iframe. Now, I want to call a javascript function on the client side as soon as the post returns and the iframe is populated. This has turned out to be much harder than I imagined. I tried hacking this by calling a method when the button is pressed and continuously sleeping until the iframe is populated but couldn't get it to work. What is the proper way to do this? I found some examples relating to "postback", but all of those seemed to be related to ASP.NET. What is the python equivalent?

Comment: Added the contents of clearIFrame(), see my edit.

Comment: You can't just add an `onload` on your `iframe?` You can also use `postMessage` to post from child frame to parent

Comment: oh, wasn't aware I could add an onload to the iframe. Let me try. Also, what is "child frame"?

Comment: I actually did try something like this - document.getElementById('my_iframe').onload = function() {
       alert("message");
    } but it did nothing.

Comment: The `iframe` on your page, you can have javascript running that can post messages to the parent page that is hosting the iframe

Comment: Have you tried using inline attribute event handler `onload`?

Comment: Actually, now the onload seems to work. Not sure what was wrong before. That might solve it.

Comment: What does the function do? https://jsfiddle.net/jLqftx0k/

Comment: It actually works now with the onload on the iframe. Thanks everyone for the help!